# Get day, month, year, hour, minutes and seconds in XSLT 3.0

Tags: xslt-3.0

In my XSLT file, I need to record the current timestamp on which I am hitting the backend database in below XML tags

```
               <DateTimeOrdered>
                    <Day>3</Day>
                    <Month>6</Month>
                    <Year>2022</Year>
                    <Hour24>7</Hour24>
                    <Minute>7</Minute>
                    <Second>7</Second>
                    <MilliSeconds>150</MilliSeconds>
                </DateTimeOrdered>
```

In C# it's very easy to achieve, can someone please suggest me how this can be achieved in the XSLT file?

Comment: The XPath (2 and later) expression language you use in XSLT 2 and later an a datatype `xs:dateTime` which takes a date-time value in the format `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sss` for its constructor so you just need to make sure you construct such a string from your various components and pass that to the `xs:dateTime` constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to find the solution.

In my Azure APIM Inbound policy, I want to post the current timestamp while hitting the backend URL.

So initially I have declared variables like below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ax82b.png)

Post that declaration I have used those variables like below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQbmu.png)

and at the end I used the variable like below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onyFF.png)

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Code should be pasted as text, and formatted using Markdown. (The toolbar in the Stack Overflow editor can help you with this.) Code within images is harder to read, less accessible, can't be copied, and doesn't show up in relevant searches. Please [edit] your post to include the code as text; this will help you get better responses, and help prevent your answer from getting deleted.